# Java Multithreading & Adding to Static Field

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, loops, static

I want to write a program that runs 3 concurrent threads in the main method which adds words to a static field `infiList` with type `ArrayList<String>` using an infinite loop.

I know how to create threads and to run them but I don't know how to add them to the `infiList`. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Multithreading implements Runnable {

public Multithreading () {
    //
}

// Implement the run method in Runnable
public void run() {
// Tell system how to run custom thread

}


public static int infiList(ArrayList<String>) {

    return t1;
}

public static void main (String args[]) {

    // Create an instance of the class
    Multithreading task = new Multithreading();

    // Create a thread
    Thread t1 = new Thread(task);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(task);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(task);

    // Start a thread
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
 }

}
```

Comment: "I know how to create threads and to run them" I hope you do realize, that in your code you didn't start a single `Thread`? Btw. if you implement `Runnable` you need to override the `run`-method

Comment: and what is `t1`? your code doesn't make sense, why do you post something, that will not even compile?

Answer (score 0):

You define what you thread will do in the 'run' method, inside it you have to update the static list with words.

Use a static list with threads is a very bad idea because of concurrency issues: threads will update the same memory location and overrides will show up, use

```
Collections.synchronizedList
```

when you create the list

Comment: "Static list" doesn't make any sense.  A List can't be static.  Only a _variable_ can be static, but in Java, a variable can never hold a List; it can only hold a _reference_ to a List.  Of course, that distinction doesn't matter if only one variable ever refers to the List, but in Java it is possible (and frequently useful) for more than one variable to refer to the same object.

Comment: "Use a [shared] list with threads is a very bad idea."  Why?  It is impossible for threads to communicate with one another except through shared objects, and there are many use cases for threads sharing a List.

Comment: "Use `Collections.synchronizedList`."  The object returned by `Collections.synchronizedList(l)` _is_ a List.  That is to say, it is an object that implements the `List` interface.

Comment: When I said static list I Mean this: private static final List<?> list. That is, a static instance of List (Arraylist or whatever you want), I think is clear and does not need specifications. Using static, as Orla said (not shared, a shared list does not have to be static, can be a member class ), is a bad idea because of threading concurrence. For avoid that, you have to use Collections.synchronizedList or another mechanism. Indeed the result is another list, but a list  aware of concurrency, thats the point. Thanks for your comments, but I think there are unneeded

Comment: I agree that it is entirely clear to _me_ what you are talking about, and it would be just as clear to all of my co-workers, but the difference between an instance and an object is not at all obvious to the newbies who ask questions here.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I agree with you in newbies point, thanks again for your comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution how to do that:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Multithreading implements Runnable {

public static ArrayList<String> infiList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        infiList.add("testing");
        System.out.print("string added");
    }
}

public static void main (String args[]) {
    // Create three concurrent threads
    new Thread(new Multithreading()).start();
    new Thread(new Multithreading()).start();
    new Thread(new Multithreading()).start();

}
}
```

of course there will be problems with the synchronization. So, make sure you are doing it properly.

Comment: I would add `synchronized(infiList){...}` into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your threads to add to a list then you must do the work in the thread and add words while the thread is running. And by infinite loop I suppose you mean a while loop so you need to create a thread class that does the work and return the string when it is finished. Take the returned string and and add it to the array.

From the looks of your code I don't think you have implemented threads correctly. Declaring Runnable just means you have a run method, which you dont. There are only two ways to implement threads. 1. Using the Thread class or a class that extends threads 2. Implementing SwingWorker class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html